# JQuery set two imgs to same position as another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been tring to set `img` at same position as another using jquery `.position()` and `.css()`

Here is the code:

```
function setImgsToSamePosition() {
    var position = $('#img1').position();
    $('#img2').css({ 'left': position.left + 'px', 'top': position.top + 'px' });
    $('#img3').css({ 'left': position.left + 'px', 'top': position.top + 'px' });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set imgs pos to be equal to img1 pos
    setImgsToSamePosition();
})
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: remove `$` before `function`. `function` is a keyword.

Comment: I did remove. Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can overlap images this way. I set the position to `fixed` then set the left and top values for both other images.  I'm not entirely sure why'd you want this; so, if it's not the desired result, just comment.

```js
function setImgsToSamePosition() {
    var position = $('#img1').position();
    $('#img2, #img3').css({ 'left': position.left + 'px', 'top': position.top + 'px' });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set imgs pos to be equal to img1 pos
    setImgsToSamePosition();
})
```

```css
img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#img1, #img2, #img3 {
  position:fixed;
}

#img1 {
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img1" src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg.jpg" />
<img id="img2" src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg2.jpg" />
<img id="img3" src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg3.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For the translation of an element to work in this way
**position: relative;
    left: 20px;**

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know what ur upto but i just corrected your code.

```js
$(function(){
    var position = $('#img1').position();
    var x = $("#img2").position();
    $("#pos").text("top: "+x.top+" "+"left: "+x.left);
    $('#img3').css({ 'left': x.left + 'px', 'top': x.top + 'px' });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" id="img1" style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" id="img2" style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>
<p id="pos"></p>
</body>
</html>
```